# Creating backups from SQL Server running on Linux machine Docker container

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker

I am running SQL Server on a Docker container on my Debian11 Linux machine. Everything works fine but I can't backup databases I created.

The command below will create a backup but I can't access it or even find it:

```
backup DATABASE testDB to disk='./test.bak'
```

And using another location would cause an access denied error, for example:

```
backup DATABASE testDB to disk='/home/brutal/backups/test.bak'
```

[image]

It is worth noting that I did make SQL Server the owner of the target folder by the following command but I am still getting the error.

```
chown -R mssql:mssql ./backups/
```

Comment: The Docker container is effectively its own little Linux VM with its own filesystem, so when it executes `backup DATABASE testDB to disk='./test.bak'` where do you think `./test.bak` is going to be inside the container's file system? Do you have a `/var/opt/mssql/backup` directory inside the container? Do you have that mapped to a directory on the Debian host?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I was not able to ls container file system, but i believe it goes there because i searched my hole drive and there were no such a file. Also i have /var/opt/mssql but no backup folder. I know it supposed to go there based on microsoft documentation but it doesn't.

Comment: I wrote about [how to get backup files _into_ a container](https://sqlblog.org/2020/03/15/attaching-restoring-databases-inside-a-container) to restore them, the same technique would work for backing up files inside the container and accessing them outside.

Comment: I also connected dbeaver to try using GUI,  buy no dumping options.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand, thank you alot, i'll try it and let you know if it works.

Comment: dbeaver can't help the database engine go across VM boundaries either. It still has to make the database engine run the backup command, and so it is the database engine that has to be able to see `folder` to place the backup there. Have you considered backing up to URL instead? Might require less gymnastics (e.g. a simple SAS token) instead of host file system access.

Comment: No i haven't, i actually thought about using an ftp server i have to backup to, but i don't know if this dbms supports such a thing or not. Or should i install a ftp client on container it self (if such thing is possible)

Comment: SQL Server has no idea what FTP is, so you'd need some other utility to intervene (and it would still have to gain access to the backups). But [it can definitely back up to blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url), and in that case it just needs outbound Internet access.

Comment: I guess i need azure for that, right?

Comment: Yes, you need Azure to back up to Azure storage.

Comment: I just found file inside container file system, thank you very much. I'll try all and i'll learn more on docker and containers. And see how i can get this file out of there.

Comment: i found the answer based on your guides and ill share it here so other can use it.
thank you all and special thanks to sir Aaron Bertrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone I found the answer.
Backups go inside the container directory and you can copy files inside and outside of a container using docker cp command like:

```
docker cp 332b4db9f705:var/opt/mssql/backup/testDB.bak ./testDB.bak
```

You can see full documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)